# How to install vim syntastic without package manager?

Tags: vim, syntastic

On syntastic repo https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic#installation, the only example they provide for installing syntastic is using pathogen.

How should install it without pathogen or any package manager?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pathogen is only needed for Vim 7 or earlier. In Vim 8 all "Pathogen's" functionality is already built-in, and you should never use it at all.

To install a plugin in Vim 8 you only have to put it under the following path: `~/.vim/pack/<bundle>/start/<plugin-name>` Here `<bundle>` can be any name of your choice. Then restart Vim and issue `:helptags ALL` to rebuild help tags, and you're done.

There still remains a question how you'll be *updating* your plugins, but you can do it manually with `git` etc.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the accepted answer I realised my problem was down to an error in the installation documentation for syntastic.

Where it says to restart vim and then type `:Helptags` it should actually say `:helptags` (with a lower-case H)